# I don't know the following syntax: (new Function1((Continuation)null)

Tags: java, kotlin, coroutine

I am learning for coroutine of Kotlin.
I want to understand principal of coroutine on jvm.

This is my toy-problem and decompiled-code as java

```
class Toy {
    val foo: suspend () -> Unit = {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            println("Foo!")
        }
    }
    
    val bob: suspend () -> Unit = {
        println("Bob!")
    }
    
    val boo: () -> Unit = {
        println("Boo!")
    }
}
```

```java
public final class Toy {
   @NotNull
   private final Function1 foo = (Function1)(new Function1((Continuation)null) {
      int label;

      @Nullable
      public final Object invokeSuspend(@NotNull Object $result) {
         Object var2 = IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED();
         switch(this.label) {
         case 0:
            ResultKt.throwOnFailure($result);
            CoroutineContext var10000 = (CoroutineContext)Dispatchers.getIO();
            Function2 var10001 = (Function2)(new Function2((Continuation)null) {
               int label;

               @Nullable
               public final Object invokeSuspend(@NotNull Object var1) {
                  Object var3 = IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED();
                  switch(this.label) {
                  case 0:
                     ResultKt.throwOnFailure(var1);
                     String var2 = "Foo!";
                     System.out.println(var2);
                     return Unit.INSTANCE;
                  default:
                     throw new IllegalStateException("call to 'resume' before 'invoke' with coroutine");
                  }
               }

               @NotNull
               public final Continuation create(@Nullable Object value, @NotNull Continuation completion) {
                  Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(completion, "completion");
                  Function2 var3 = new <anonymous constructor>(completion);
                  return var3;
               }

               public final Object invoke(Object var1, Object var2) {
                  return ((<undefinedtype>)this.create(var1, (Continuation)var2)).invokeSuspend(Unit.INSTANCE);
               }
            });
            this.label = 1;
            if (BuildersKt.withContext(var10000, var10001, this) == var2) {
               return var2;
            }
            break;
         case 1:
            ResultKt.throwOnFailure($result);
            break;
         default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("call to 'resume' before 'invoke' with coroutine");
         }

         return Unit.INSTANCE;
      }

      @NotNull
      public final Continuation create(@NotNull Continuation completion) {
         Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(completion, "completion");
         Function1 var2 = new <anonymous constructor>(completion);
         return var2;
      }

      public final Object invoke(Object var1) {
         return ((<undefinedtype>)this.create((Continuation)var1)).invokeSuspend(Unit.INSTANCE);
      }
   });
   @NotNull
   private final Function1 bob = (Function1)(new Function1((Continuation)null) {
      int label;

      @Nullable
      public final Object invokeSuspend(@NotNull Object var1) {
         Object var3 = IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED();
         switch(this.label) {
         case 0:
            ResultKt.throwOnFailure(var1);
            String var2 = "Bob!";
            System.out.println(var2);
            return Unit.INSTANCE;
         default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("call to 'resume' before 'invoke' with coroutine");
         }
      }

      @NotNull
      public final Continuation create(@NotNull Continuation completion) {
         Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(completion, "completion");
         Function1 var2 = new <anonymous constructor>(completion);
         return var2;
      }

      public final Object invoke(Object var1) {
         return ((<undefinedtype>)this.create((Continuation)var1)).invokeSuspend(Unit.INSTANCE);
      }
   });
   @NotNull
   private final Function0 boo;

   @NotNull
   public final Function1 getFoo() {
      return this.foo;
   }

   @NotNull
   public final Function1 getBob() {
      return this.bob;
   }

   @NotNull
   public final Function0 getBoo() {
      return this.boo;
   }

   public Toy() {
      this.boo = (Function0)null.INSTANCE;
   }
}
```

I tried to read decompiled code and got below questions

1. `Function1` is interface and hasn't constructor parameter. But How could we pass `Continuation` argument?
2. We could assign `() -> Unit` into `suspend () -> Unit`. It meaning for setting `() -> Unit` with `(Continuation) null` ?

thank you for your time

Comment: Without seeing the class definition of `Function` it is impossible to be sure, but in all probably you don't need the typecast. `new Function2(null)` should be sufficient unless the class is degenerate.

Comment: Decompiled code often does not look like actual valid Java code.